# Django template is not deleting the record correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

This is my template code

```
<tbody>
    {% for item in items %}
    <tr class="text-black">
      <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
      <td>
        <a
          href="{% url 'menu-options-update' item.id %}"
          class="btn btn-sm btn-user edit"
        >
          <!-- <i class="far fa-edit"></i> -->
          <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i
        ></a>
        <a
          data-toggle="modal"
          class="btn btn-sm btn-user delete btn--show-modal"
          href="#myModal"
          data-confirm="Are you sure to delete this item?"
          ><i class="fas fa-trash"></i
        ></a>
      </td>
      <div class="modal1 hidden">
        <button class="btn--close-modal">&times;</button>
        <h2 class="modal__header">Do you want to delete this record?</h2>
        <div class="deletModalBtnContainer">
          <a
            href="{% url 'menu-options-delete' item.id %}"
            class="delete-final btn"
            >Delete</a
          >
          <a href="#" class="cencel-modal btn btn-cancels-close-modal"
            >Cencel</a
          >
        </div>
      </div>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
```

And this is my view

```
def menu_option_delete(request, id):
    item = MenuOptions.objects.get(id=id)
    item.delete()
    return redirect('menu-options')
```

This code is always picking the 1st id in the table data, not the one on which I have clicked. Let's suppose my table has 5 rows and I want to delete the 4th row but after I click on the delete button it is deleting the 1st row.

URL

```
path('menu_options/<int:id>/', views.menu_option_delete, name='menu-options-delete'),
```

Comment: could you please post the view. Do you modify/access "id" in the view before the query?

Comment: no am not modifying it.
  `item = MenuOptions.objects.get(id=id)`

  `item.delete()`

Comment: can you please show the urls and aslo show the complete id how you are getting id

Comment: @sarangkkl i have updated the original question with the URL and the view please check

Comment: are you getting correct id in the views try print and confirm

Comment: @sarangkkl no am always getting the id of the 1st record of the table that's why I think that the problem is in template

Comment: try this in your template at delete link menu_options/{{item.id}}/

Answer (score 1):

I have also same problem after an 20 hour research I got solution as below:

you have to send id to modal using **data-target="#{{ item.id }}"**, **href="#{{item.id}}"** and set modal id: **id="{{ item.id }}">** so that modal can pass that id to view.py

```
<tbody>
{% for item in items %}
<tr class="text-black">
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="{% url 'menu-options-update' item.id %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-user edit">
            <!-- <i class="far fa-edit"></i> -->
            <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
        </a>
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{ item.id }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-user delete btn--show-modal"
            href="#{{item.id}}" data-confirm="Are you sure to delete this item?"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
        <div class="modal hidden" id="{{ item.id }}">
            <button class="btn--close-modal">&times;</button>
            <h2 class="modal__header">Do you want to delete this record?</h2>
            <div class="deletModalBtnContainer">
                <a href="{% url 'menu-options-delete' item.id %}" class="delete-final btn">Delete</a>
                <a href="#" class="cencel-modal btn btn-cancels-close-modal">Cencel</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>

</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: it did not resolve the issue, still getting the same problem

Comment: @ Devam Sanghvi
i believe we are close to solving this problem could you please look into this again.

Comment: In my case I am using button insted of <a href>

Comment: I edited my Answer by replacing "modal1" to "modal" and added href=#{{item.id}}

Comment: Now its not even opening the modal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241386/discussion-between-devam-sanghvi-and-the-knight).